# undefined method `reject' for false:FalseClass in Carmen::Country.named("Libya").subregions?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, carmen

I'm using rails version 5.1.5 and Carmen, and when I do:

```
Carmen::Country.named("Libya").subregions?
```

in the rails console, after including carmen succesfully, I get this error:

> "NoMethodError: undefined method `reject' for false:FalseClass"

But for other countries it works fine. For example:

```
Carmen::Country.named("United States").subregions?
```

returns `true`. What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 0):

The issue was with an empty file in the yml data for subregions, in the gem folder. carmen-1.0.2/iso_data/base/world/ly.yml.